# Extracting a variable from an executable

Tags: executable

I'd like to extract the `M__hello_` variable of this [code](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Python/frozen.c?revision=81029&view=markup) from the executable (for learning purpose). I'd like to have this array back in a variable in any programming language Do you know how can I do this ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "extract" the variable.  It's a static variable, if you meant the value of the variable, it's right there. Here is the string representation of that array : "cs dGHdS(sHello world...N((((shello.pys?s"

Answer (score 3):

Find the offset of the variable in memory. Using either your debugger or a look like Cheat Engine.

After this you can use `ReadProcessMemory()` from `kernel32.dll` in Windows to read the variable in your own program.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After looking at how an executable is made, I found that the variable's content was stored in a data segment, since it's a global variable. With p7zip, I got this data segment, but is there a way to parse it or to know where each fragments begin and end by disassembling the EXE?

(I'm knew to reverse engineering, so I'm just wondering how everything is working.)

Comment: strings -o msgbox.exe | findstr Great ---------------------------------------                                                            
2073:Win32 Assembly is Great!  --------------------------------                                                      strings is from sysinternals findstr is an inbox utility